# Change checkbox checked with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to change a part of my html code with JavaScript, but I can't get it to work:

```js
function trigger(){
  document.getElementById('mycheckbox').innerHTML="<input type="checkbox" id="mycheckbox" checked>";
}

function triggerOff(){
  document.getElementById('mycheckbox').innerHTML="<input type="checkbox" id="mycheckbox">";
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="mycheckbox"> 

<button type="button" onclick="trigger()">test</button>
<button  type="button" onclick="triggerOff()">test</button>
```

So if I press the button I want to add the checked status to my HTML and if I press the other button I want to remove the checked status.
Is this even possible?

All help is highly appreciated ! Thanks a lot guys!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot set `innerHTML` to input type `checkbox`. Use the `checked` property to check/uncheck the checkbox

```js
function trigger(){
  document.getElementById('mycheckbox').checked = true;
}

function triggerOff(){
  document.getElementById('mycheckbox').checked = false;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="mycheckbox"> 

<button type="button" onclick="trigger()">test</button>
<button  type="button" onclick="triggerOff()">test</button>
```

Comment: thanks for the answers! I know that I could do it with .checked= true/false. But I was trying to get the change persistant. So If I reload the page the checked is still there. I don't want to do it with local storage.

Answer (score 2):

Use `checked` property, like this:

```js
function trigger(){
  document.getElementById('mycheckbox').checked=true;
}

function triggerOff(){
  document.getElementById('mycheckbox').checked=false;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="mycheckbox"> 

<button type="button" onclick="trigger()">test</button>
<button  type="button" onclick="triggerOff()">test</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just do it like that

```
function trigger(){
  document.getElementById('mycheckbox').checked = true;
}

function triggerOff(){
  document.getElementById('mycheckbox').checked = false;
}
```

The innerHTML property will create inside your `mycheckbox` another `input` element